# Whose spaceship is Tony Stark in?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the [latest trailer](https://youtu.be/hA6hldpSTF8) of *Avengers: Endgame*, Tony is shown in a spaceship where he records a message.

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Tony was stranded on Titan. The spaceship he was travelling in was crashed there. And Nebula also crashed her spaceship while others were fighting with Thanos.

So, my question is, **which spaceship is this?** This one seems not to have any damage.

Comment: I'd guess it's the Milano but it doesn't seem to match quite right.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot should have gone with your gut, it is indeed the Milano.

Comment: @AAlig Bar eyeballing, which I did and it didn't match up quite right, is there any evidence?

Comment: It sure looks like the Milano to me.  What in particular doesn't seem to match quite right?

Comment: If you don't believe that the cockpit and the profile shot look identical to the Milano, would you believe several websites calling the ship the Milano? 
http://toofab.com/2018/12/07/trailer-for-avengers-endgame-is-here-captain-america-cries-hawkeye-returns http://www.multiversitycomics.com/news/avengers-endgame-reveal/

Comment: Is this one of these things that are trivially answered by simply waiting to watch the actual film this is a trailer for? Is there more we can do for now than speculate how he might get a new ship in the actual film?

Comment: Doesn't this belong to "we don't know" because the movie isn't out yet. So answers can only be speculative & POB.

Comment: @AJ But to what end? Won't this question be entirely useless in half a year? Also, you *think* it can be definitely answered, but you don't know, noone does. And you only think that because you either read the answers already or you already made up an  answer for yourself.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson You're bordering on an existential question here, We only ever _think_ we know anything because of what we've seen or been told. As far as the answer, I have provided different categories of "proof" that this is indeed answerable. 1. The interior of the ship in the trailer matches the interior of the ship in my answer. 2. The exterior of the ship matches the exterior of the ship in my answer. 3. Tony would logically have access to this ship, as they are known to have been in the same location, and this is the only known ship at that location. (continued)

Comment: (continued) 4. Multiple online resources are stating that the ship in the trailer is indeed the one named in my answer. 
Short of a quote from the producers themselves i don't think this could be more definitive.  
So, contrary to your assertion, we DO know the answer to this question, and it is no more useless or subjective than any other identification or "is this possible" question (of which there are several on this stack).

Comment: @AAlig We're not debating the correctness of your answer here, though. Those comments would make better additions to your actual answer.

Comment: Putting this question on hold doesnt make sense.  Let it stand, its a legit question and I was wondering the same thing.

Comment: He built it in a cave with a box of scraps.

Comment: It should be noted that this ship is NOT the *Milano*...it's the [***Benetar***](https://screenrant.com/guardians-galaxy-infinity-war-ship-name-benatar/). The Milano was never completely repaired in GotG2

Comment: @Paulie_D good catch, I forgot that it wasn't rechristened with the name of the original

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Tony is flying the **Benetar** <s>Milano</s>, the ship belonging to the Guardians of the Galaxy. This makes sense, as we know the guardians piloted this ship to Titan and we are never shown it being damaged or destroyed. The large 4 windowed area where he is recording his message is the cockpit (compare to [this clip from Infinity War](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mf0Mk1yZZY0)), and at 0:20 in your linked video, we can see the ship in full view.

Several websites are calling it the Guardians ship as well: [thewrap](https://www.thewrap.com/the-biggest-takeaways-from-that-dope-first-avengers-endgame-trailer/), [toofab](http://toofab.com/2018/12/07/trailer-for-avengers-endgame-is-here-captain-america-cries-hawkeye-returns), [multiversitycomics](http://www.multiversitycomics.com/news/avengers-endgame-reveal/)

(I had forgotten that the Milano was not repaired in GOTG2, but was replaced instead. The Guardians ship throughout Infinity War is named The Benetar. - thanks to Paulie_D for bringing that up)

Comment: We'll probably get an explanation on how he gets into it and out into space in the film.

Comment: Completely off-topic but are these ships named after 80's icons (Alyssa) Milano and (Pat) Benetar?  I knew the name of the original ship but not the second, which got me wondering